# Como cambiar un string de precio en php

Tags: php, mysql, html5, mysqli

Estoy teniendo problemas al imprimir el precio de mis productos por tanto lo quiero cambiar, me explico hago mi consulta sql

```
SELECT * FROM sinventario,as_precios WHERE sinventario.FI_CODIGO = as_precios.FI_CODIGO
```

guardo mi los datos en un array y los imprimo

```
  while ($filas = $db->recorrer($sql)){
            $FI_PRECIO= $filas['FI_PRECIO'];
    echo $PRECIO1;
 }
```

pero me imprime el precio asi Bs. "8221.85" y lo que quiero es que me lo imprima asi Bs. "8.221,85"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asumiendo que el valor obtenido sea un número, puedes usar la función [number_format](http://php.net/manual/es/function.number-format.php) para utilizar los separadores que deseas.

Veo también que aparentemente estás haciendo `echo` a una variable no definida, entonces voy a asumir que imprimes `$FI_PRECIO`.

```
while ($filas = $db->recorrer($sql)) {
    $FI_PRECIO = number_format($filas['FI_PRECIO'], 2, ",", ".");
    echo $FI_PRECIO;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Aquí lo que puedes hacer  desde MySQL es darle un formato de esta forma:

```
format("12347",2)
```

Y esto te devolverá 12,347